# Get previous month where column is in YYYYMM numeric datatype

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

In SQL Server how do I get previous month where column is in YYYYMM numeric datatype like 202101?

I need default last month value every time

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as integers? This is a really bad practice.

Comment: Previous to WHAT value? The current date? Some random row that exists in a table? A variable? "I need default" also sounds like some type of interface requirement (e.g., a report parameter). It might also a default constraint for a column or a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, please, use `date` for dates instead of integers that can't be validated and require hacks and tricks to make act like dates.

```
DECLARE @t table ( i int IDENTITY(1,1), col int);

INSERT @t(col) VALUES(202001),(202102);

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(col/100, col%100, 1)) FROM @t;
```